# facebook ios background request fails silently

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to perform a graph API call when the app is in background.

I have a method that does the following (I will include only the relevant piece):

```
- (void) facebookFetch
{
    NSString* query = @"<my_query">;
    NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
    [FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:
                              FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests,
                              nil]];
    // Make the API request that uses FQL
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                           parameters:queryParam
                           HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                        id result,
                                        NSError *error) {
                      if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                      } else {
                        NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                      }
                    }];

}
```

What I have here is that, **if i call this function while the app is in foreground**, I get the response.

Now, the problem is that I need to call this function even in background, so I've implemented the following function:

```
/** Background task **/
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"####### background task!");

    if (![FBSession activeSession].isOpen) {
      NSLog(@"fbsession is NOT open!");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"fbsession is open!");
      [self facebookFetch];
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
```

}

I got the "fbsession is open!" message, so I correctly enter in the relevant code, but then I don't receive any response.

As you can see I log the request, and here's what I have **in both cases**:

```
URL:    https://graph.facebook.com//fql?sdk=ios&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED&q=<my_query>&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20131212&format=json
Method: GET
UserAgent:  FBiOSSDK.3.13.1
MIME:   multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
```

But as I told you before, in the background situation I don't receive the reply.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);` inside the completion block for `facebookFetch`.

```
- (void) facebookFetch:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))backgroundCompletion
{
    NSString* query = @"<my_query">;
    NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
    [FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:
                              FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests,
                              nil]];
    // Make the API request that uses FQL
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                           parameters:queryParam
                           HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                        id result,
                                        NSError *error) {
                      if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                      } else {
                        NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                      }

                      if (backgroundCompletion) {
                          backgroundCompletion(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                      }
                    }];

}

/** Background task **/
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"####### background task!");

    if (![FBSession activeSession].isOpen) {
      NSLog(@"fbsession is NOT open!");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"fbsession is open!");
      [self facebookFetch:completionHandler];
    }
```

}

You'll need to update any other calls to `facebookFetch:` and you can pass in `NULL` (or `nil`).

Comment: thanks, I've tried but without success. In fact, I think that I never enter in the piece of code inside the completionHandler, so I don't see any "Error:" or "Result:" message and so I don't reach the `if (backgroundCompletion)` part

Comment: How long does `FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:` usually take? You've got 30 seconds to do something inside of [`-application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)

Comment: It's quite fast, from the log where I call the same code:
The request: 
`2014-04-13 14:34:48.547 FriendsMonitor[4774:70b] FBSDKLog: Request <#1119>: URL: https://graph.facebook.com/`

The reply:
`2014-04-13 14:34:49.596 FriendsMonitor[4774:70b] FBSDKLog: Response <#1119> Duration: 1049 msec Size: 4 kB Response Body:`

Comment: Have you enabled the application for background fetches? See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24

Comment: Yes, actually the "background" method is called, it's only the Facebook request that doesn't return the result. I was reading that this can happen because of threading problems, but in this case I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Instead of a log statement try putting a breakpoint inside the `completionHandler` block

Comment: I've tried putting a breakpoint in the `if (backgroundCompletion)` but (when in background) is never reached

Comment: Is anything displayed in the console (in the Organizer in Xcode), right after `fbsession is open!`?

Comment: only the request thanks to the `[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects: FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, nil]];` line, but I never see the reply (because I never enter in the completionHandler) :\